# Names of Files with accent mark in assets folder

Tags: android, assets

I need to manage in Android Studio names of files with accent marks in assets folder like (á,é,í,ó,ú),
but when I launch the application send this message "Files under the build folder are
generated and should not be edited".
Somebody know if it's possible manage files like this in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can put accent marked folders in "Assests" folder without any issue.
2. you can put accent marked folders in  "auto-generated" folders also. But you can not access them.
3. but you can not edit auto-generated folders or files as you wanted.

Comment: Hi DavidJhons. I refer to names of files in folder assets, e.g. corazón.mp3, campeón.bmp, bebé.mp3, parís.jpg, etc.

Comment: So whats the point, you can put any file in  to assets folder

Comment: of course, but when i launch my app, send this error "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited"

Comment: This is the error: c:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\PruebaMusica\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\musica\bebé.mp3  Error:Invalid filename. Unable to add

Comment: i have edit the  answer , build folder is a system generated folder, you can not access, read/write them as you wanted